# Is it good practice to store variables as attributes of another variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, storage

I recently started storing variables (such as X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test) as attributes of their full dataframes. It has helped me organize different training and testing datasets when I'm using more than one simultaneously. Is this generally considered good/okay practice? Here's an example:

The way I learned it originally was:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(some_dataframe[features],\
    some_dataframe[target]
```

The way I started doing recently:

```
some_dataframe.X_train, some_dataframe.X_test,\
    some_dataframe.y_train, some_dataframe.y_test = \
    train_test_split(some_dataframe[features], some_dataframe[target]
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. `some_dataframe.X_train` is pandas syntax for referring to a column

Comment: I think you've also got some confusion about the difference between "methods" and "attributes", which is making it less clear what you're asking. I think we need more code to understand exactly what you're implementing. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would prefer a wrapper class composed of the df with these other attributes.

Comment: I don't have the time or will to write up all the things I think are wrong with this but I'd liken it to running with scissors.  You're more likely to hurt yourself than others.

Comment: @roganjosh you can stilly dynamically add attributes to dataframe objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but is that actually what happens in this case? I don't get how pandas can differentiate the syntax otherwise, or at least it would seem to me to be clumsy to have something like that. Now the dataframe goes back to behaving more like a regular python object (I know it technically always _is_ but that feels like blurring of syntax). I just don't understand why they implemented `.col_name` in the first place tbh...

Comment: Good point @roganjosh, actually a pandas dataframe is not a "*regular* python object" as it has some supplementary properties that people expect. By adding attributes the way it is done here, you kind of break the "contract" that comes with a pandas dataframe. So you have a to have really good reason to do that...

Comment: @roganjosh thanks. I've changed it to attributes. pandas doesn't seem to have any syntactical problems with this as you can't create new columns via an attribute. If you already had a column with that name it would probably throw an error.

Comment: I think @godot is right - a dictionary is a better way of doing this!

Comment: @roganjosh it isn't a blurring of syntax or anything. dataframes probably overload their `__getattr__` to check if the attribute corresponds to a column, then returns it, or raise attribute error. But setting an attribute will still work like any other python object. *Why* they did it, well, probably because for the use-case of data-analysis, it comes in handy. A lot of non-software engineers use `pandas` for just data-analysis, not building quality code bases

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm curuious about what you think of my comment on the answer, then. "Blurring" of syntax was only meant in terms of a mental model. I would personally say that expectation is pretty important here, regardless of whether or not I happen to understand how it can work either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr: If you can't find a *really* good reason, avoid merging.**

I think that what you are doing is part of what is called **"bad opportunity"**.

As I can't know all the details behind your choice, I am not saying that it is a bad idea but your description of your problem seems to point at a usual problem regarding merging different sources of data together.

What you want is *regroup all of your data* in a data structure to distinguish them from other sources of data, so I guess you thought why not use something that is already available, why not use this "vaguely related" dataframe that I just used?

But you should ask yourself why is *this* data structure relevant for what you want to achieve ? What makes it the right data structure ? Are you going to use the previous data of this df with the new one ? Or are you just picking up this structure because it's "there"?

If there is no reason for you to use specifically this data frame, ***I would simply create a new data structure, probably a dictionary would be enough***.
In your specific case, some reasons are:

1. A data frame is probably an overshoot for what you are looking for.
2. You loose some nice properties of the previous data frame by putting together different things (e.g. what's the dimensions of your dataframe now? How many rows?)
3. People/you could get confused between the different parts of your data frame. For example, when you will mutate your data, are you sure you will know which data the transformation will be applied to? Will you remember which data is part of the "original" data frame and what were added afterwards?

To conclude, to fusion different data (or ideas in general) in one structure (concept) is always risky, you should always do it for a good reason and not just because you can.

PS: See the questions @roganjosh ask in the comments as good examples of the problems that emerge when you start putting together things that weren't not meant to be.

Comment: I think you're right. but a small correction - adding an attribute doesn't change the original dataframe. so your original data remains untouched, but you can access the changed dataframe as an attribute of the original dataframe.

Comment: @JoeB well it technically does because it's still the same object but now you've just bolted an attribute on the side. If I inherited a code base and just saw `some_dataframe.X_train` floating around, and _then_ I found out it was a bolt-on attribute and not the syntax for a DataFrame column, that I've begrudgingly come to accept, I would not be too happy. I think the point being made is that we have some expectation as to what the syntax represents, rather than trying to say that the existing data was changed in any way